# GAE: SortOptions Expression distance()

Tags: java, google-app-engine

even if I use the distance() function for ordering my documents in the Google App Engine I get this Warning and my documents are not sorted as I expected.

```
Jän 20, 2015 9:25:10 AM com.google.appengine.api.search.dev.ExpressionBuilder makeExpression 
WARNING: Function distance not implemented. Using dummy expression.
```

This is the Java-Code I use:

```
SortOptions sortOptions = SortOptions.newBuilder()
            .addSortExpression(SortExpression.newBuilder()
                .setExpression("distance( geopoint(" + latitude + ", " + longitude + "), geocode)")
                .setDirection(SortExpression.SortDirection.ASCENDING))
            .build();

        QueryOptions options = QueryOptions.newBuilder()
                .setLimit(50)
                .setSortOptions(sortOptions)
                .build();

        Query query = Query.newBuilder().setOptions(options).build("");
        Results<ScoredDocument> result = getIndex().search(query);
        return result;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found answer by my own:
On the Java development-server it's not implemented as you can see [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/devserver).